# Why does Bazel have a module registry?

Tags: bazel

I'm new at Bazel and looking at the experimental Bazel module feature, one thing raises a question in my head: why does it need a [module registry](https://bazel.build/build/bzlmod#registries)?

Go language (also developed at Google) has a similar module dependency mechanism and yet it does not have a registry, it can pull modules straight from their source code repos.

Maintaining the registry itself (even if it's just a GH repo right now) *is* some work. Requiring module authors to open PRs for every new versions of a module is not a fantastic UX. So I imagine there is some advantages but those are not super clear to me.

The only thing I can think of is that it's kind-of nice to centralize all modules metadata in a single place. But this does not hold since Bazel authorises users to implement their own registry to pass it to the build with the [repeatable `--registry` flag](https://bazel.build/build/bzlmod#selecting-registries).

Again, I am sure I'm missing something but since I'm struggling to find the answer, I thought it might be worth asking the question here.

Comment: As someone who works with registries for other ecosystems (e.g. Nuget gallery, npmjs, Docker), the absence of a registry for go is more surprising to me than the presence of one for Bazel.

Comment: The design doc is here: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1moQfNcEIttsk6vYanNKIy3ZuK53hQUFq1b1r0rmsYVg/edit And for more visibility, you might consider asking this on bazel-discuss@googlegroups.com: https://groups.google.com/g/bazel-discuss

Comment: Thanks for the link, apparently Bazel also supports "Single-module registry", which is basically equivalent of not having registries at all.
@Damien_The_Unbeliever - Curious to get your thoughts on why not having a registry in Go is surprising. I understand it's a bit of an anti-pattern, but I'm still struggling to find out what having a registry brings you in terms of functionality.